# Leibniz rule for Hadamard derivative?

Tags: integration

I'm having difficulty computing the Hadamard derivative of the following functional $\tau(F)$, where $F$ is a distribution function:

$$
\tau(F)=\int_{1-F(0)}^1 F^{-1}(s)ds.
$$

The difficulty here is that the lower limit of the integral varies with $F$. I am not finding a Leibniz rule for differentiation under the integral sign with variable limits for the Hadamard derivative. I have tried working this out myself by adapting the proof of the Leibniz integral rule, but the Leibniz rule uses the mean value theorem. I have found a mean value theorem for the Frechet derivative which could perhaps be modified to work for the Hadamard derivative,$^*$ but that theorem is an inequality.

In general, given two functionals $\phi,\psi:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, is it true that if

$$
\theta(g)=\int_{\phi(g(0))}^1 \psi(g(s)) \,ds,
$$ 
(suppose that $\phi\leq 1$ always so the order of the integral limits makes sense.)

then

$$
D_g\theta(g)=-\psi(D_g\phi(g(0)))+\int_{\phi(g(0))}^1 D_g\psi(g(s)) \,ds\,?
$$

$^*$ The mean value theorem for Frechet derivatives to which I am referring  can be found here

> Ambrosetti, A. and Prodi, G. (1995). A Primer of Nonlinear Analysis. Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics. Cambridge University Press. Theorem 1.8, p. 13.

I found the reference while searching this website in an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300772/when-can-we-move-a-fr%C3%A9chet-derivative-under-a-lebesgue-integral) question.